# Images Styles are not created in public directory in Drupal 9 with openlitespeed server

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, server, drupal, openlitespeed

I've moved recently my drupal 9 website from nginx webserver to openlitespeed.

The website was working as expected, but now it is not. I've defined a rule when uploading a new image, it should be converted to webp.

When you try to select an image, it doesn't display in the preview as it should (See the screenshot below). The image even doesn't get uploaded in the `sites/default/files/styles` folder. I've made sure that the permission for the styles folder is set to *755* and everything works well.

[image: 1]

The strange thing is that this is happening only with the images that have rules set in the responsive image styles, the ones that don't, are working as expected (the ones which go to the `sites/default/files`, see screenshot above)

[image]

For example:
The URL of the image = https://example.com/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/products/samsung-tv-1_0.png.webp?itok=b7z4aF-X - the server doesn't load it.

Once I add index.php after the domain name, and access manually this URL - https://example.com/index.php/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/products/samsung-tv-1_0.png.webp?itok=b7z4aF-X -  the server puts this image to the right directory (in this case `sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/products/`) and it loads automatically every time, even if refresh the page or clear the cache.

See screenshot: [image: 3]

I use an openliteserver standard virtual host configuration

```html
docRoot                   /home/example.com/public_html/web
vhDomain                  $VH_NAME
vhAliases                 www.$VH_NAME
adminEmails               admin@example.com
enableGzip                1
enableIpGeo               1

errorlog $VH_ROOT/logs/example.com.error_log {
  useServer               0
  logLevel                WARN
  rollingSize             10M
}

accesslog $VH_ROOT/logs/example.com.access_log {
  useServer               0
  logFormat               "%h %l %u %t "%r" %>s %b "%{Referer}i" "%{User-Agent}i""
  logHeaders              5
  rollingSize             10M
  keepDays                10
  compressArchive         1
}

index  {
  useServer               0
  indexFiles              index.php, index.html
}

errorpage 403 {
  url                     403.html
}

errorpage 404 {
  url                     404.html
}

errorpage 500 {
  url                     500.html
}

scripthandler  {
  add                     lsapi:elect55477846 php
}

phpIniOverride  {

}

extprocessor elect55477846 {
  type                    lsapi
  address                 UDS://tmp/lshttpd/elect55477846.sock
  maxConns                10
  env                     LSAPI_CHILDREN=10
  initTimeout             60
  retryTimeout            0
  persistConn             1
  pcKeepAliveTimeout      1
  respBuffer              0
  autoStart               1
  path                    /usr/local/lsws/lsphp80/bin/lsphp
  extUser                 elect5547
  extGroup                elect5547
  memSoftLimit            2047M
  memHardLimit            2047M
  procSoftLimit           400
  procHardLimit           500
}

context /.well-known/acme-challenge {
  location                /usr/local/lsws/Example/html/.well-known/acme-challenge
  allowBrowse             1

  rewrite  {

  }
  addDefaultCharset       off

  phpIniOverride  {

  }
}

rewrite  {
  enable                  1
  autoLoadHtaccess        1
}

vhssl  {
  keyFile                 /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
  certFile                /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
  certChain               1
  enableECDHE             1
  renegProtection         1
  sslSessionCache         1
  enableSpdy              15
  enableStapling          1
  ocspRespMaxAge          86400
}

module cache {
storagePath /usr/local/lsws/cachedata/$VH_NAME
```

which points to the drupal root directory and from there loads rewrite rules from `.htaccess` file which is also standard. (provided by drupal)

```html
#
# Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
#

# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|install|make|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|twig|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl|yml)(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)?$|^(\.(?!well-known).*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|composer\.(json|lock)|web\.config)$|^#.*#$|\.php(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)$">
  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order allow,deny
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

# Add correct encoding for SVGZ.
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz

# Most of the following PHP settings cannot be changed at runtime. See
# sites/default/default.settings.php and
# Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel::bootEnvironment() for settings that can be
# changed at runtime.

# PHP 7, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
  php_value assert.active                   0
</IfModule>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive On

  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    # Do not allow PHP scripts to be cached unless they explicitly send cache
    # headers themselves. Otherwise all scripts would have to overwrite the
    # headers set by mod_expires if they want another caching behavior. This may
    # fail if an error occurs early in the bootstrap process, and it may cause
    # problems if a non-Drupal PHP file is installed in a subdirectory.
    ExpiresActive Off
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Set a fallback resource if mod_rewrite is not enabled. This allows Drupal to
# work without clean URLs. This requires Apache version >= 2.2.16. If Drupal is
# not accessed by the top level URL (i.e.: http://example.com/drupal/ instead of
# http://example.com/), the path to index.php will need to be adjusted.
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  FallbackResource /index.php
</IfModule>

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # Set "protossl" to "s" if we were accessed via https://.  This is used later
  # if you enable "www." stripping or enforcement, in order to ensure that
  # you don't bounce between http and https.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]

  # Make sure Authorization HTTP header is available to PHP
  # even when running as CGI or FastCGI.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  # Block access to "hidden" directories whose names begin with a period. This
  # includes directories used by version control systems such as Subversion or
  # Git to store control files. Files whose names begin with a period, as well
  # as the control files used by CVS, are protected by the FilesMatch directive
  # above.
  #
  # NOTE: This only works when mod_rewrite is loaded. Without mod_rewrite, it is
  # not possible to block access to entire directories from .htaccess because
  # <DirectoryMatch> is not allowed here.
  #
  # If you do not have mod_rewrite installed, you should remove these
  # directories from your webroot or otherwise protect them from being
  # downloaded.
  RewriteRule "/\.|^\.(?!well-known/)" - [F]

  # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
  # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
  # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/foo will be redirected to http://www.example.com/foo)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://www.example.com/foo will be redirected to http://example.com/foo)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  # RewriteBase /

  # Redirect common PHP files to their new locations.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?/(install\.php) [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?/(rebuild\.php)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !core
  RewriteRule ^ %1/core/%2 [L,QSA,R=301]

  # Rewrite install.php during installation to see if mod_rewrite is working
  RewriteRule ^core/install\.php core/install.php?rewrite=ok [QSA,L]

  # Rewrite sites/default/files/styles
  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/files/styles/(.+)$
  # RewriteRule ^(.+)/files/styles/(.+)$ index.php/$1/files/styles/$2 [R=302,L]

  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

  <IfModule LiteSpeed>
  CacheLookup on
  </IfModule>

  # For security reasons, deny access to other PHP files on public sites.
  # Note: The following URI conditions are not anchored at the start (^),
  # because Drupal may be located in a subdirectory. To further improve
  # security, you can replace '!/' with '!^/'.
  # Allow access to PHP files in /core (like authorize.php or install.php):
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/core/[^/]*\.php$
  # Allow access to test-specific PHP files:
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/core/modules/system/tests/https?\.php
  # Allow access to Statistics module's custom front controller.
  # Copy and adapt this rule to directly execute PHP files in contributed or
  # custom modules or to run another PHP application in the same directory.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/core/modules/statistics/statistics\.php$
  # Deny access to any other PHP files that do not match the rules above.
  # Specifically, disallow autoload.php from being served directly.
  RewriteRule "^(.+/.*|autoload)\.php($|/)" - [F]

  # Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
  # Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve correct content types, and prevent double compression.
    RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1,E=no-brotli:1]
    RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1,E=no-brotli:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
      # Serve correct encoding type.
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
      # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>

# Various header fixes.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  # Disable content sniffing, since it's an attack vector.
  Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
  # Disable Proxy header, since it's an attack vector.
  RequestHeader unset Proxy
</IfModule>
```

Any idea what this would happen and how I can get this working?

Comment: When the image is not showing, what's the error in the web console or the server error log?

Comment: @Eric in the web console is making a GET request to https://example.com/404 and the response is also 404. So when it's trying to load the image, because it doesn't exist, the servers redirect it to a 404 page.

Comment: Forgot to mention, the OLS Drupal after 2022.7 should have it fixed by adding a context.